# Puedo con Triggers identificar que campo se updateo? Para guardar un historico de este

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

La idea es quitarle esa tarea a un programador; para ver si se entiende mas explico un poco lo que se le encargaría al programador:

1. Identificar en cada `update` los campos que se editaron
2. Con esto, guardaría en una tabla replica de la original(tablahistorico) solo en los campos editados osea insertaría los datos los viejos

   - ademas también de identificar y guardar el usuario que edito y tal vez como un plus - guardar el nombre de los campos editados para encontrar mas fácil

Actualmente guardo todo el registro pero de esta manera es difícil ver lo que se edito realmente.

**EDIT1**

Tengo la tabla `ordenunds` con campos `idunds ,dato, ordenunds, usuario`

y la tabla `ordenunds_hist` `idunds,dato, ordenunds, usuario,fecha,triggeredby`

El trigger en la tabla  `ordenunds`

```
AFTER UPDATE ON  `ordenunds`
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO `ordenunds_hist` 
     (`idunds,dato, ordenunds, usuario,fecha,triggeredby`)
   VALUES
     (NEW.idunds, new.dato, new.ordenunds,new.usuario, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'UPDATE')
```

Lo que me guarda los cambios de todos los campos y ademas la fecha en que se hizo y que fue hecho por la ejecución de un `UPDATE`

lo que pensaba yo era meter un IF antes del INSERT INTO donde le diga que si se ejecuto por un cambio en el campo ORDENUNDS no ejecute la insercion, pero si se ejecuto por un cambio en ese y en cualquier otro o solo en cualquier otro si la ejecute, pero nose como hacer que
 "..mediante el mismo trigger se pueda evaluar los campos de la tabla y verificar que dato se haya modificado."

Comment: Si, si se puede. Con un tigger before update -> https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_update.php

Comment: actualmente uso esos before update, pero mi duda va en como identificar que campo se edito con eso? digamos que en una tabla de 20 campos solo 1 se edito y yo inserto toda la fila en el historico; para ver cual se edito tendría que revisar los 20 datos nuevos vs los 20 datos viejos lo cual no es optimo. Nose si se entienda mejor.

Comment: Personalmente eso es parte de la lógica de programación. Hasta dónde tengo entendido mysql no controla la eventualidad de los campos, sino de las tablas en donde se ejecutan los triggers. Esto no quiere decir que no se pueda con un poco de creatividad del desarrollador, ya que mediante el mismo trigger se puede evaluar los campos de la tabla y verificar que dato se haya modificado. Pero eso ya sugiere que edites la pregunta y muestres código, modelo E-R o tablas para poder ser más precisos y saber como estas intentando hacerlo. Las modificaciones se harán en base al codigo que tengas avanzado.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado es "...mediante el mismo trigger se puede evaluar los campos de la tabla y verificar que dato se haya modificado" exactamente mi duda, agregue informacion de mi trigger actual, y un ejemplo de lo que hago actualmente a ver si se entiende mejor

Comment: probaste algo del tipo `if (NEW.dato <=> OLD.dato ) THEN SET NEW.dato = 'sincambios'; END IF;` ?

Comment: No @aloMalbarez no lo habia intentado, no tenia conocimiento de que podía hacer eso la verdad, no tiene el 100% del resultado que quería obtener pero me ayuda bastante a lograrlo! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que hacer eso con cada campo de la tabla, el campo que no sea igual es el campo modificado, y no solo puede ser un campo sino varios.